# Laravel 5 url.intended broken when session driver is set to cookie

Tags: session, redirect, session-cookies, laravel-5.1

Our Laravel 5.1 application has been using the "native" session driver setting (configured in the .env file). With it set this way, we were able to use the laravel url.intended behavior to redirect the user to the url they were attempting to access prior to being authenticated.

We had to change it to "cookie" because every time we use Amazon's Opsworks system to deploy a new build, users were logged out because their server-side session files were no longer available. Once we changed it to cookie, the users remain logged in even when we deploy a hotfix or new build.

However, with it set to cookie, the url.intended does not work at all. I tried hacking together some solution by adding a custom url intended node, but it just won't work. It seems like when the user attempts to access a url prior to being logged in, it sets the session info, but then the application redirects the user to the login page where it's getting nulled out.

I'm using Debugbar to look at the session vars and I'm going crazy. I'm already bald so I have no more hair to pull out.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-intended-not-giving-the-intended-behavior is having a similar problem, the issue was his custom middleware. Do you have a custom middleware for this?

Comment: I think the best option is to use redis or memcached as session driver.. thats way it will be persistent even on servers changes

Comment: Thanks @BrynnBateman. I had reviewed that one and as near as I can tell, we aren't using a custom middleware. When I upgraded to Laravel 5.1, I followed their directions and the only change we made was to add ONE middleware function but that's for admin users, which isn't where we are having a problem. Otherwise, all I did was to change the "before" in the routes to "middleware" per the Laravel instructions.

Comment: @amirbar I've never used Redis or Memcached. If I change it to one of those, is it going to cause issues? Do I need to install Redis or Memcached?

Comment: yes you will have to install them on the server, for my multi servers sites, I have 1 server for session which all servers connect to, than no mather what server the user is on he will always have the same session

Comment: @AndrewChristensen yes you would need to install Redis/Mem on your server or anywhere the application is running. It shouldn't cause any issue to use them, you wouldn't need to use them for any purpose other than storing a session. It would bother me to have what seems like an unresolved bug somewhere, though - up to you.

Comment: its also good choice for caching driver

Comment: Also consider using a debugger to step through the code one line at a time - I use Xdebug with PHPStorm to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up setting up a Dynamo database at first and then transitioned to Redis on a common server. We have a load balancer and don't want sessions getting lost or corrupted by switching servers so all cache is now being stored in that common location.